# Better compression than LosslessFactory in PDFBox?

Tags: java, apache, pdf, png, pdfbox

Losslessfactory in PDFBox seams to do a very bad job at compressing PNGs. Looking at the code it seems it doesn't do what it's Javadoc says (use LZW) [1], but I might be wrong.

Any ideas on how to pipe a binary PNG stream with exec through e.g. pngquant and then create a PDImageXObject from the resulting binary?

```
images-001-000.png PNG 2480x3508 2480x3508+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.261MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Reducing the pixels, writing it with PDFBox, extracting with pdffiles and using identify returns

```
images-shrink-001-000.png PNG 874x1237 874x1237+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.038MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Although the pixel count is much, much smaller, the image is only slightly smaller.

Using quantization to show the maximal possible reduction I use pngquant for comparison,

```
images-quant-001-000.png PNG 874x1237 874x1237+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 673KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

[1]

```
    /**
     * Create a PDImageXObject while making a decision whether not to 
     * compress, use Flate filter only, or Flate and LZW filters.
     * 
     * @param document The document.
     * @param byteArray array with data.
     * @param width the image width
     * @param height the image height
     * @param bitsPerComponent the bits per component
     * @param initColorSpace the color space
     * @return the newly created PDImageXObject with the data compressed.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private static PDImageXObject prepareImageXObject(PDDocument document, 
            byte [] byteArray, int width, int height, int bitsPerComponent, 
            PDColorSpace initColorSpace) throws IOException
    {
        //pre-size the output stream to half of the input
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteArray.length/2);

        Filter filter = FilterFactory.INSTANCE.getFilter(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
        filter.encode(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray), baos, new COSDictionary(), 0);

        ByteArrayInputStream encodedByteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        return new PDImageXObject(document, encodedByteStream, COSName.FLATE_DECODE, 
                width, height, bitsPerComponent, initColorSpace);
    }
```

Comment: Likely a bad javadoc. However png compression isn't supported by the PDF specification. Flate is usually the best. Combining Flate and LZW might sometimes bring a slight improvement. Anyway, the next version version (2.0.12) will support predictor enhanced Flate compression: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4184

Comment: You can test 2.0.12 here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.12-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: i have a PDF with PNGs , reduce the size of the images by >50% pixel wise, but writing those with  PDFBox results in a very low decrease of PDF size (~5%). If I recode everything with JPGs the size of the PDF decreases 70%. So I assume most of the size of the PDF is in the images. This hints at the code that generated the PDF did a much better job with the PNGs than PDFBox does. It looks like LosslessFactory.createFromImage doesn't have a lot of parameters like size of the palette etc.

Comment: I can't comment on that because I haven't seen the PDF and I don't understand what you mean "rewriting them with PDFBox results in a very low decrease of PDF size". How was the PDF written in the first place? What is "rewriting them" - just load and save?

Comment: "reduce the size of the images by >50% pixel wise" means reducing the number of pixels by more than 50%. "how was the PDF written in the first place"? I don't know, it's an example PDF with images. "rewriting them" means taking the images, reducing their pixel size, then using " resources.put(cosName, imageData)" to put them back in the PDF. Then the PDF is written to a byte array with "    doc.save(byteArrayOutputStream)" and the size of the byte array is compared to the initial size of the PDF.

Comment: The main size compression of PNG today comes from quantization I guess, so "pngquant" binary data might work with PDFs. I also don't understand why the Javadoc refers to LZW when this is not allowed in PDFs.

Comment: ok I got it. Still would like to see the PDF. No, there are no parameters like size of the palette, i.e. color reduction. You should do this yourself before calling PDFBox. I'm not really surprised that deleting pixels of a specific image doesn't have much improvement. Most of what you eliminate is repetition. LZW is allowed in PDFs, but pngquant isn't. LZW alone is usually worse than Flate compression. Build your own jar by replacing FLATE_DECODE with LZW_DECODE in that file and you'll see.

Comment: Maybe you think that png files land 1:1 in a PDF, but this isn't the case. This is only with JPG and JPX files and (somewhat) TIFF. Other files are decoded and then encoded.

Comment: You're much more knowledgeable than I am, but I'm at a loss here. Quantization is reducing the number of colors and dithering the results, so why would this not be allowed in a PDF? "You should do this yourself before calling PDFBox." So I need to create a color reduced BufferedImage that I then hand to Losslessfactory?

Comment: Yes you'd need to prepare some lower quality image and pass that one. Or use jpeg with high compression. In both cases your images won't look as good as before.

Comment: PDF supports various "filter" types, one of them being the Flate decode algorithm. In addition, the Flate decode algorithm supports using a predictor function to pre-process the input. Now, if you look at the PNG specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/) you will find that it *also* uses the Flate decode algorithm together with a predictor. And the PDF spec actually references the PNG spec with respect to the predictor. So a PNG can often be just embedded into a PDF. However, if re-compression is necessary it depends on the compression algorithm how small the result will be.

Comment: @gettalong Thanks for the additional insights. I also added some data to the question.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Also thanks to you, as I've learned some more things about PDFs and PNGs.

Comment: @gettalong No a PNG cannot "be just embedded" in a PDF. The Flate filter is not PNG but PNG uses the Flate algorithm.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by the new question, but I think it has 2 parts: 1) call an external tool and pass this to java, that isn't really my activity area; 2) this is more something for a compression specialist. Btw if you extract images from PDFBox the Flate encoded images will be converted back into PNGs. So it also depends how good java is. Anyway I recommend that you try the 2.0.12 version (see first 2 comments), the PDF files should be smaller. If your images have less than 256 colors then indexing should help (not implemented).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You are right, I didn't phrase that correctly. PNGs cannot be embedded directly like JPEGs. But it is still possible for some types of PNGs to just take the IDAT chunks, combine them and put them into a PDF stream object and put the meta data into dictionary of the stream. In such cases the IDAT objects don't need to be de-predicted nor de-compressed, thus allowing an optipng/pngcrush/... optimized PNG to be "embedded".

Comment: @gettalong Yes, it is possible to directly embed the IDAT data of a compressed PNG into a PDF. iText does this (at least the old 2.1 version; I did not look into the current iText version (license ...) but I don't think it lost this feature). This is a feature that PDFBox is still missing. createFromByteArray() and all createFromFile???() in PDImageXObject should be extended that it can directly reuse the IDAT of the given PNG. I don't know when I will have time to look into that, feel free to volunteer.

Comment: You can use JPEGFactory which works well for me